# Crossed random slope intercept model with nlme::lme, "translated" from lme4::lmer

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

I want to specify a linear mixed model. I have to use nlme because of heteroscedasticity. It's easy to specify the random structure of my model with `lme4::lmer`: 
`lmer(Y ~ X (1 + X | a) + (1 + X | b), ...)`
How would the random term be translated to `nlme`?  I couldn't figure it out using information from the internet.
I tried this: 
 
`lme(Y ~ X, random = list(X = ~a, X = ~b), weights = varIdent(form=~1|X), ...)`, 
  but the model does not converge.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I believe one of the issues is that your random effects are misspecified, should be `random = list(a = ~X, b = ~X)` if you want to make the same model as the `lmer` model.

Comment: I tried this out but still get this errormessage:  `nlminb problem, convergence error code = 1
  message = singular convergence (7)`

Comment: It could be that your model is simply over-specified. Hard to say. Have you tried a simpler model in `nlme`?

Comment: ok, I think I'll reduce the model to a random intercept model. What I did now is the following:
`conlob$const = factor(rep(1, nrow(dataframe)))` 
and then  
`random <- list(const=pdBlocked(list(pdIdent(~a-1), pdIdent(~b-1))))` 
However, in the summary, i get
`Block 1: [...]  Formula: ~a - 1 | const`
and 
`Block 2: [...]  Formula: ~b - 1 | const`
This would be a random slope Model. How can I change it?

Comment: You don't need a constant column of 1's for the intercept, both `lme4` and `nlme` create this automatically. To create a random intercept model `random = list(a = ~1, b= ~1)`. I recommend this article: http://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer it concerns longitudinal data analyses (which is probably different from what you want) but provides a nice comparison between `lme4` and `nlme`. I would start by removing the `weights` adjusting the random structure (see above)  and see if the models are the same. Then continue building the var/covar matrix. Or post a reproducible example.